# Writing to txt file in Python

Tags: python, output, text-files

I'm having issues printing to a txt file. The file contains information stored in bytes. No matter what I try, I can only get the output to print in the shell. Here's what I have - any help is welcome.

```
def main():
    with open("in.txt", "rb") as f:
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte != "":
            print ord(byte), 
            byte = f.read(1)


with open('out.txt','w') as f:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        f.write(main())
        close.f()
```

Comment: your `main` function has no return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of what various functions and methods do. You are writing the returned value of `main()` to the file, expecting `main`'s `print()` calls to go to the file. It does not work like that.

```
def main():
    with open("in.txt", "rb") as f, open('out.txt','w') as output:
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte != "":
            output.write(str(ord(byte))) 
            byte = f.read(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Use `file.write()` to write strings (or bytes, if you're using that kind of output, which you currently aren't) to a file. For your code to work, `main()` would have to return a complete string with the content you wanted to write.

Comment: Thank you very much - obviously I'm still learning. I really appreciate your explanation. This seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `print ord(byte)` from within `main()`. This prints to the console.

You are also calling `f.write(main())` which appears to assume that `main()` is going to *return* a value, but it doesn't.

It looks like what you intend to do is replace the `print ord(byte)` with a statement that appends your desired output to a string, and then `return` that string from your `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the string from the function `main`. You are currently printing it and returning nothing. This will assemble the string and return it

```
def main():
    with open("in.txt", "rb") as f:
        ret = ""
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte != "":
            ret = ret + byte 
            byte = f.read(1)
    return ret


with open('out.txt','w') as f:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        f.write(main())
        close.f()
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I can use all the help I can get :)